# how to get all visibable component in scroll view in react native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, flatlist

I have a scroll View which have various items but while scrolling I want to which all items are in view port.
I want to achieve the same functionality (already exists in flatlist)
`const onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems }) => {   };`

I didn't find any method